# java BufferedImage to int[] issue

Tags: java, arrays, int, bufferedimage

I have a BufferedImage (Type.TYPE_INT_ARGB) that I want to convert to a `int[]`. I do this by using the following method: 
`((DataBufferInt)src.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();`. But when I do this with an image, it gives me the wrong array size. For a `320 x 240` Image it makes a `57,600` size `int[]` when it should give me a `78,600` size array. Do you know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with

```
src.getRGB(0,0,image.getWidth(),image.getHeight(),null,0,1);
```

Comment: I just use this way because it is the first way I learned. I'll try that now.

Comment: "That didn't work" is not helpful. Have a look at the javadoc and play with the parameters a bit - I don't have your code.

Comment: It turns out that the source image is supposed to be 320x240 but it is 240x240. My bad

Comment: Ugh. And I though I was up late.

Comment: It's slow, that's what's wrong with it. :-) (It's not a bad suggestion though, as it will always give the expected results, but at the expense of possible extra color conversion and always array copy).